# if count of a select sql is > 0 then union the result with another sql's result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL as follows:

```
SELECT
  ''                   AS "something1",
  'a pre defined text' AS "something2",
  ''                   AS "something3"
FROM dual

UNION ALL

SELECT
  rownum AS "something1",
  resultset.*
FROM (
       SELECT
         t1.abcd AS "something2",
         t2.xyz  AS "something3"
       FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2
       WHERE t1.mnp = t2.mnp
       ORDER BY "something2"
     ) resultset;
```

This SQL produce the result like:

```
something1      |      something2      |      something3
-------------------------------------------------------------
                 a pre defined text               
1                value of abcd from t1  value of xyz from t2
2                value of abcd from t1  value of xyz from t2
```

and so on...

The first line in the result comes from the select part of dual (line 1 to 5) and the remaining lines are comes from the subsql of the UNION clause (line 7 to 17).

Now the challenge is the result from the dual (line 1 to 5) should be present if any result found from the subsql (line 7 to 17).

For example if any result found from the subsql then the final output will be same as above, otherwise as follows:

```
something1      |      something2      |      something3
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to achieve it? I have tried some approaches but not succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a condition on the standard hard-coded row to only be displayed if the second selects returns any row, like the example below:

```
select
  '' as 'something1',
  'a pre defined text' as 'something2',
  '' as 'something3'
from 
  dual
  where exists (select 1 from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 where t1.mnp = t2.mnp)
union all
select
  rownum as 'something1',
  resultset.*
from (
  select
    t1.abcd as 'something2',
    t2.xyz as 'something3'
  from 
    table_1 t1, table_2 t2
  where 
    t1.mnp = t2.mnp
  order by 
    'something2'
) resultset;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please fix all obvious problems in your code *before* posting:

- you're using single quotes around column aliases - that's illegal and is rejected by the SQL compiler
- don't use line numbers in SQL statements - they're making it unnecessary difficult to copy & run the statement
- consider using ANSI style JOINs instead of the old Oracle syntax

Your problem per se can be solved by using the analytical function `COUNT()` to count the number of rows whose something1 is NOT NULL:

`count(something1) over (partition by 1) as cnt`

After computing this count, you can then apply a WHERE clause to filter out rows whose cnt equals 0. Your overall query (slightly re-written, with example data):

```
 with table_1 as
 (select 'abcd from t1' as abcd,
         1 as mnp
    from dual),
table_2 as
 (select 'xyz from t2' as xyz,
         1 as mnp
    from dual),
resultset as
 (select t1.abcd as something2,
         t2.xyz  as something3
    from table_1 t1
    join table_2 t2
      on t1.mnp = t2.mnp
   order by something2),
resultset_plus_dummy as
 (select null as something1,
         'a pre defined text' as something2,
         '' as something3
    from dual
  union all
  select rownum as something1,
         resultset.*
    from resultset),
resultset_with_cnt as
 (select r.*,
         count(something1) over(partition by 1) as cnt
    from resultset_plus_dummy r)
select *
  from resultset_with_cnt
 where cnt > 0
```

Comment: I used the line numbers intentionally to understand easily, however someone removed those line numbers and its ok, and thanks for your valuable suggestions.